# Use of undeclared identifier?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I am getting error:`use of undeclared identifier`
here is the code for view controller where I am accessing the object of model class `mapMembersData`

```
 for (NSMutableDictionary *getMemberElements in arData) 
 {
   mapMembersData *notModelObject = [mapMembersData sharedInstance];//showing error
   [notModelObject assignMemberData:getMemberElements];
   [memberArray addObject:notModelObject];
 }
```

Here is the code of model class:

```
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>
#import <Google-Maps-iOS-Utils/GMUMarkerClustering.h>

@interface mapMembersData : NSObject<GMUClusterItem>

@property(nonatomic,retain) NSString *chatToken;
@property(nonatomic,retain) NSString *address;
+ (mapMembersData *)sharedInstance;
- (mapMembersData *)assignMemberData:       
@end


#import "mapMembersData.h"
#import "Constants.h"
@implementation mapMembersData
@synthesize chatToken,
address,

static mapMembersData *instance;

+(mapMembersData *)sharedInstance{

@synchronized(self)
{
    instance = [[super alloc] init];
}
return instance;
}


- (mapMembersData *)assignMemberData:(NSMutableDictionary*)getMemberElements
{
  chatToken = [objdelegate checkIfStringIsEmpty:[getMemberElements 
  objectForKey:@"chatToken"]];
  address = [objdelegate checkIfStringIsEmpty:[getMemberElements 
  objectForKey:@"address"]];
  return self;
 }
@end
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @pawan: pardon, couldn't understand why u need screen shot from the console? Code ain't compiling, whenever I create the object of the model class.

Comment: have you added import ?

Comment: is the `@interface mapMembersData` you have shown in .m file?
`+ (mapMembersData *)sharedInstance;` needs to be in .h

Comment: @HarishPathak yes i have imported in viewcontroller.

Comment: Show the import.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After scratching my head for a day. I manage to get ride off the bizarre errors. 
Finding starts from below:

1.`mapMembersData`-class were residing in two different folders of the workspace (In `XYZ`-folder and one at outside the folder). `mapMembersData`- the class was referenced by project i.e inside `XYZ` and other was just placed.

2. the controller from where I was accessing the `mapMembersData`, was at outside `XYZ`-folder, thus creating ambiguity.

I deleted unused referenced classed and confirm controller should access correctly.

Answer (score 0):

In your `storyboard` there must be a controller, in which you had set a class with storyboard id, and you removed that class from that storyboard but the storyboard id is still addressing it, like below image:

[image]

So you have to remove that Storyboard ID and uncheck that "Use Story Board ID".

That's all.

Comment: Sorry project is old one created on xib. It makes sense if project used the story board.